# Change NSString after initialization to @"" (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c

Experts,

I wanted to find out if the following piece of code is correct. I know NSStrings are immutable but most times I want them initialized to empty string so I don't have to check if they are null. The code runs fine but I wanted to make sure it doesn't cause any issues.

```
NSString *myString = @"";
if (i > 0) {
  myString = @"The message";
}

... use myString without testing for null
```

Comment: Understand that while an NSString is immutable, *pointers* to an NSString are not.  That is, you can readily substitute the address of one (immutable) NSString for another.  You're not changing the value of the original string, you're changing the value of the pointer to the string.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's perfectly fine like that.